# Real Time internet connection checker in python With GUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, queue, python-multithreading, internet-connection

so basically what i am trying to do is to check if the computer have access to internet till the end of the program....

It is in a GUI which is made with tkinter.....I tried to create new thread and run the function in a while loop(while 1:), but it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

.

.

.

RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

this is the program

```
import threading
import socket
import time

def is_connected():
    try:
        socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
        print("Online",end="\n")
    except OSError:
        print("offline",end="\n")

tt3 =threading.Event()

while 1:
    t3=threading.Thread(target=is_connected)
    t3.start()
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is the program with GUI

```
import threading
import socket
import time
import tkinter
top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("")
l=tkinter.Label(top,text='')
l.pack()

def is_connected():
    try:
        socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
        print("Online",end="\n")
        l.config(text="Online")
    except OSError:
        l.config(text="offline")
        print("offline",end="\n")

tt3 =threading.Event()

while 1:
    t3=threading.Thread(target=is_connected)
    t3.start()
    time.sleep(1)

top.configure(background="#006666")
top.update()
top.mainloop()
```

any suggestion or help is most welcomed!!
(someone in reddit suggested me to use queue about which i have no idea )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the while loop will block the tkinter mainloop from processing events.  Second you are repeatedly creating new thread in each loop.

Better use `.after()`:

```
import socket
import tkinter

top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("Network Checker")
top.configure(background="#006666")

l=tkinter.Label(top,text='Checking ...')
l.pack()

def is_connected():
    try:
        socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80)) # better to set timeout as well
        state = "Online"
    except OSError:
        state = "Offline"
    l.config(text=state)
    print(state)
    top.after(1000, is_connected) # do checking again one second later

is_connected() # start the checking
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks...This works awesome. I thought no one will answer this